# Add style to specific part of string in an Object prop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, components, react-props

Here, the **`desc`** key has a value which is a string;

```
const kataData = {
  name: "Katarina",
  img: "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Katarina_0.jpg",
  desc: "The Sinister Blade, Passive: Voracity",
};
```

This is passed as a prop to my React component as so:

```
// component to hold vars
const Champ = (props) => {
  const {name, img, desc} = props;
  return (
    <div className="SmartApp">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <img src={img} alt={name} style={{width: "300px"}} />
       
      // here {desc} = props.desc
      <p>{desc}</p>


    </div>
  );
};

// main App
export default function ChampApp() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Champs Ranked</h1>
      <Champ name={kataData.name} img={kataData.img} desc={kataData.desc} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So here, `kataData.desc` is set to pass the string directly to my component and the text shows up as expected on my site.

What i can't seem to find out is how to change certain Html elements inside this string, for example, making a section of the string bold like so:

```
desc: "The Sinister Blade, <b> Passive: </b> Voracity"
```

any tag (like the `<b>`) directly translates as plain text and I seem can't figure out how to separate a section of the string out to make changes the I normally would with a `<span>` tag.

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `innerHTML` to display the strings HTML.

1. Change the `<p>` tag:

```html
<p id="champ_desc"></p>
```

2. Create a function to insert HTML:

```js
function _renderDesc(){
  let _ele = document.getElementById('champ_desc');
  _ele.innerHTML = desc;
}
```

3. Call this function on `componentDidMount` or by using useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  _renderDesc();
}, []);
```